# Identity Server 3 - signin parameter for external login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-identity, identity, identityserver3

I am using identity server 3 and I have configured facebook and google as my external login providers.

I have a registration page where I have to show the facebook and google links. When I check the url for that I can see it follows the below format

```
../identity/external?provider=Google&signin=e41e8ad48d1f282610767112c22a7984
```

I am stuck with the signin parameter. From where can I generate or get a valid signin parameter so that I can generate a valid link.

Comment: As is the question does not make a lot of sense. First you say "when I check the url [of the generated links]...I can see..." then you ask about generating a valid link.

Comment: @CrescentFresh The signin parameter is a dynamic Id generated by identity and it will become invalid after some time. In the default login page of Identity server these are coming through some interface. I need to show the same links in another part of my custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no point in generating a `signin` id dynamically, because it will be generated automatically if a there's a valid request for `connect/authorize` endpoint.

But if you insist on generating `signin` id yourself, `identityserver3` has an [extension method](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Extensions/OwinEnvironmentExtensions.cs#L116) for that, which you can use it.

```
owinContext.Environment.CreateSignInRequest(new SigninMessage(){});
```

Comment: Hi Arvin yes this is what I needed. I need the signin Id since I have to show external login providers in a custom page outside of the default views of Identity server.